# What is default encryption policy that is used to perform encryption/decryption of Azure blobs

Tags: java, azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure-storage sdk version: 8.3.0
com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions has a field 'encryption policy' (BlobEncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy). BlobEncryptionPolicy needs implementation of IKey and IKeyResolver.

Does azure provide any implementation of IKey and IkeyResolver or default BlobEncryptionPolicy that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

azure-keyvault-core contains the IKey and IKeyResolver. It is a small package with no dependencies. The storage client library for Java defines it as a dependency.Create a BlobEncryptionPolicy object and set it in the request options (per API or at a client level by using DefaultRequestOptions). Everything else will be handled by the client library internally.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption-java?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

You may also refer the suggestion mentioned in this [link](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobEncryptionPolicy.html)

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.